# jsReport not reading data through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsreport

I am using jsreport.net to create a report. I am trying to use an array of data to bring it into a chart that uses JavaScript to function, but I am having trouble calling the data to the JavaScript. A table that i mad before works and it is as follows:

```
<div id="table" style="height: 300px; width: 50%;">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="border: 1px solid">Date of restock</th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid">Units sold</th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid">Total profit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each sale}}
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid">{{date}}</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid">{{units}}</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid">R {{profit}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

My data looks like this:

```
{
"sale":[{
    "date":"20 January 2018",
    "units":"549",
    "profit":"1514"

},{
    "date":"16 February 2018",
    "units":"483",
    "profit":"1332"

},{
    "date":"23 March 2018",
    "units":"678",
    "profit":"2596"
}]
}
```

And the chart looks like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart= new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer2", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "Progress of the number of units sold per restock"
    },
    axisY:{
        includeZero: false
    },
    data: [{        
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
            {{#each sale}}
            { y: {{profit}}, label: {{date}} }
            {{/each}}
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
<div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

I am new to this jsreport so please don't scold me if there is something I missed. Please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. All it needed is quotation marks around date.

```
"{{date}}"
```

And the profit needs to an integer not a string

Answer (score 0):

convert data into js string using function from asset global helpers.js
this results into something like var data = { "a": "foo" }
which gets afterwards interpreted in chrome into object
var obj = {{{toJS date}}};